# Split time series in intervals of non-uniform length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, intervals

I have a time series with breaks (times w/o recordings) in between. A simplified example would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(13), columns=["values"], 
    index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020 11:00:00',end='1/1/2020 23:00:00',freq='H'))
df.iloc[4:7] = np.nan
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df

                     values
2020-01-01 11:00:00 0.100339
2020-01-01 12:00:00 0.054668
2020-01-01 13:00:00 0.209965
2020-01-01 14:00:00 0.551023
2020-01-01 18:00:00 0.495879
2020-01-01 19:00:00 0.479905
2020-01-01 20:00:00 0.250568
2020-01-01 21:00:00 0.904743
2020-01-01 22:00:00 0.686085
2020-01-01 23:00:00 0.188166
```

Now I would like to split it in intervals which are divided by a certain time span (e.g. 2h). In the example above this would be:

```
(                       values
 2020-01-01 11:00:00  0.100339
 2020-01-01 12:00:00  0.054668
 2020-01-01 13:00:00  0.209965
 2020-01-01 14:00:00  0.551023,
                        values
 2020-01-01 18:00:00  0.495879
 2020-01-01 19:00:00  0.479905
 2020-01-01 20:00:00  0.250568
 2020-01-01 21:00:00  0.904743
 2020-01-01 22:00:00  0.686085
 2020-01-01 23:00:00  0.188166)
```

I was a bit surprised that I didn't find anything on that since I thought this is a common problem. My current solution to get start and end index of each interval is :

```
def intervals(data: pd.DataFrame, delta_t: timedelta = timedelta(hours=2)):
    data = data.sort_values(by=['event_timestamp'], ignore_index=True)
    breaks = (data['event_timestamp'].diff() > delta_t).astype(bool).values

    ranges = []
    start = 0
    end = start
    for i, e in enumerate(breaks):
        if not e:
            end = i
            if i == len(breaks) - 1:
                ranges.append((start, end))
                start = i
                end = start

        elif i != 0:
            ranges.append((start, end))
            start = i
            end = start

    return ranges
```

Any suggestions how I could do this in a smarter way? I suspect this should be somehow possible using `groupby`.

Comment: why would there be only two groups in your example?  The second group spans 5 hours. And why did `14:00:00` disappear?

Comment: oh, wait, I think I get it now: you'd like to split where there is more than some threshold duration. Still, not sure what happened to `14:00`, probably an oversight?

Comment: Oh yes `14:00` was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the very convenient [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```py
dt = pd.Timedelta('2H')
parts = np.split(df, np.where(np.diff(df.index) > dt)[0] + 1)
```

Which gives, for your example:

```py
>>> parts
[                       values
 2020-01-01 11:00:00  0.557374
 2020-01-01 12:00:00  0.942296
 2020-01-01 13:00:00  0.181189
 2020-01-01 14:00:00  0.758822,
                        values
 2020-01-01 18:00:00  0.682125
 2020-01-01 19:00:00  0.818187
 2020-01-01 20:00:00  0.053515
 2020-01-01 21:00:00  0.572342
 2020-01-01 22:00:00  0.423129
 2020-01-01 23:00:00  0.882215]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pierre thanks for your input. I now got to a solution which is convenient for me:

```
df['diff'] = df.index.to_series().diff()
max_gap = timedelta(hours=2)

df['gapId'] = 0
df.loc[df['diff'] >= max_gap, ['gapId']] = 1
df['gapId'] = df['gapId'].cumsum()

list(df.groupby('gapId'))
```

gives:

```
[(0,
     values                date            diff  gapId
  0     1.0 2020-01-01 11:00:00             NaT     0
  1     1.0 2020-01-01 12:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     0
  2     1.0 2020-01-01 13:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     0
  3     1.0 2020-01-01 14:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     0),
 (1,
      values                date            diff  gapId
  7      1.0 2020-01-01 18:00:00 0 days 04:00:00     1
  8      1.0 2020-01-01 19:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     1
  9      1.0 2020-01-01 20:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     1
  10     1.0 2020-01-01 21:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     1
  11     1.0 2020-01-01 22:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     1
  12     1.0 2020-01-01 23:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     1)]
```